# Can't dispatch DDM chunk, no handler defined, application has stopped suddenly

Tags: android

I wrote an app for Android 3.2 and it works fine.  But when I try to port it Android 1.5 it gives the error message "ActivityManager: Can't dispatch DDM chunk 46454154: no handler defined".  The app deploys to the emulator find but when I try to run it it says "application has stopped suddenly" without giving any stack track error or anything I can see.  So this really is a question about how to debug this message since other posts which I read here suggest that this "DDM chunk" message is not too important.

regards,

WER

Answer (score 1):

These are entirely two different errors. Usually, I find that the application will stop suddenly if I attempt to open a new activity and forgot to declare the activity in the manifest file. The other message, "Can't dispatch DDM chunk xxxxxxxxxxxx: no handler defined," will occur even when my app runs fine. I have read that it is a message that means that your app requirements and AVD are slightly incompatible. For example, if you have Android 3.2 installed for ad purposes, and you test the app on a Android 2.1 emulator, you will get this message.